# Mysql database multiple successive requests fail

Tags: java, mysql

All of my database access methods have been working up until now. I have a string of n usernames separated by ";", and I want to make n separate select statements to check if the user is online or offline. However, when used, this method returns nothing (""). The database connection is working. Any solutions are welcome.

EDIT:

New method, still does not work:

```
    public static String CheckOn(String users) {
    String toreturn = "";   
    PreparedStatement stmt2 = null;
    ResultSet rs2 = null;
    try {
        conn = Database.getDBConnection("test");
        String sql = "SELECT name FROM sessions WHERE name=?";  
        stmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);         
        String[] usarr = users.substring(1, users.length()).split(";");
        for (int i = 0; i <usarr.length;i++){
            if (usarr[i].equals("Empty")){
                toreturn = toreturn + "-";
            }
            else{
                stmt2.setString(1, usarr[i]);
            rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery();
                if (rs2.next()){
                toreturn = toreturn + "y";
                }
                else{
                    toreturn = toreturn + "n";
                }
                rs2.close();
            }

        }

        rs2.close();
        stmt2.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt2 != null)
                stmt2.close();
        } catch (SQLException se2) {
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return toreturn;
}
```

Comment: I can't see where you are iterating the ResultSet

Comment: Where is `rs` declared?

Comment: Here: if (rs.first()==true){
                    toreturn = toreturn + "y";
                }
                else{
                    toreturn = toreturn + "n";
                }

Comment: rs is declared at the top: public class Database { 
 static Connection conn = null;
 static PreparedStatement stmt = null;
 static ResultSet rs = null;

Comment: That's not iterating through the ResultSet, please go read how to use ResultSet. And why declare ResultSet as a field? Use it as local variable, no need field, it will only prevent the GC from collecting the memory. Same goes for the `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Why not split up the string containing the usernames with `String[] userlist = users.split(";");` ? This will simplify your code a lot.

Comment: I do not need to iterate through it, I just need to know if the row exists. I'll try using it as a local variable

Comment: @DarbininkaiBroliai I agree with mosquito in a sense that your code is unnecessarily complex. Maybe you could choose a list to iterate (userList as suggested by Ollie above) or the resultset. What do you think?

Comment: Great advice there guys, gonna try it now, thank you. And the split() function is really handy

Comment: Nop, still doesn't work, but the code looks nicer now

Comment: Any other advice guys?

Comment: If `rs.next()` then a row exists

Comment: You might want to use a StringBuilder instead of concatenation with toreturn.  For example, stringBulider.append("y")...

Comment: It was just full of my stupid mistakes, but now it works. It was most probably a problem with declaring the resultset and statement as static, though I'm not sure now. So If anyone posts an answer that incorporates these changes, I'll set it to correct. Thank you!